# How add 2 hours in SQL Vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

How to add 2 hours to the following date select '2014-04-02 12:00'

I tried this but with no success

```
select '2014-04-02 12:00' + 120::TIMESTAMP
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select datecol + interval '2 hour'
```